# Using theHarvester modules in my own script - sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'foo' was never awaited

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to use some of `theHarvester` modules in my own script.
I have cloned the latest version of `theHarvester` from GitHub and it works perfectly when executed from terminal.

This is the code in my script:

```py
import theHarvester
from theHarvester.discovery import baidusearch

baidu = baidusearch.SearchBaidu("example.com", 100)
baidu.do_search()

emails = baidu.get_emails()
```

This is the error:

> RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'SearchBaidu.do_search' was never awaited
> baidu.do_search()
> RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
> sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'SearchBaidu.get_emails' was never awaited
> RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

I have searched this error and looked at the code in theHarvester but can't find the problem.

I get the same error when using all other modules in the same way.

This is a link to the module in theHarvester I am trying to use:

https://github.com/laramies/theHarvester/blob/master/theHarvester/discovery/baidusearch.py

Any help is much appreciated.